# How to turn mui stepper connect into a progress bar? Each step has step content as well

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want mui stepper connector to behave like a progress indicator.
Each step also has step content part. The step content and connector are two separate divs and I am unable to style it. Can anyone please help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Cant you use MobileStepper component and set varient to progress [Progress MobileStepper](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stepper/#progress).

-Also try to create a sandbox, so we can see what you trying to achieve and help you with it.